# How to use nesting similar to firestore for google datastore?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I've worked with `firestore` previously, we can keep `documents` inside collection, and collections inside documents. For google datastore kind is similar to collection and entity similar to documents, how can we keep kind inside kind?

For firestore

```
collection
   - document
     - collection
       - document
         .... so on
```

How to achieve this for `Google Datastore`?

```
kind
   - entity
     - kind
       - entity
         .... so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for Datastore is pretty good

Start with the documentation on [Ancestor paths](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths) to learn about parent and children entities.

Be careful on ensuring you're aware of the tradeoffs that exist in Datastore as you build your database. See [Limits](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits#limits)

Depending on your language|runtime, there are tools like [`ndb`](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/index.html) for Python3 that provide abstractions upon Datastore. I've not used any of these but `ndb` used to be very popular with App Engine developers (using Datastore) and these may abstract some of the complexity in dealing with Entities in Datastore.